# Porque el button no cambia el contenido del texto - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo una duda de porque sucede esto en Javascript.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
  var button = document.querySelector('button'),
      text_button = button.textContent;

  button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    text_button = "This text has been changed"
  });

})
```

```html
<button>This text dont change</button>
```

Me explico, tengo un boton, que al dar click deberia cambiar su texto por el texto especificado en el codigo de arriba. Bueno talvez me diras que para cambiar el texto, facilmente agrego `button.textContent = "here goes something"` y cambia sin problemas. Pero si ya especifique antes una variable con el contenido del boton, ¿Porque al llamar esa variable no cambia el contenido del boton?. He probado con una alerta o un console y realmente si cambia. Esto servira mucho si deseas que un texto cambie en varias ocasiones y no tener que escribir `button.textContent`. Realmente nose porque el texto no cambia con solo llamar la variable `text_button`. Agradeceria que me despejen esta duda.

Comment: La propiedad `textContent` es un `string` que contiene el valor del texto del nodo, no es una referencia al mismo.

Comment: Entonces, la mejor manera seria como lo especifico arriba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Esta es la razón

---

La razón por la que no cambia el texto del botón es porque cuando defines la variable `text_button` almacenas en ella el valor de la propiedad `textContent` del botón y no su referencia:

```js
// Se almacena su valor y no su referencia:
var text_button = button.textContent;
```

Es decir, no hace referencia sobre la propiedad. Lo que hace es tomar su valor.

### Comparando ambos casos:

La primera hace efectivamente lo que mencionas en la pregunta y quieres evitar. Agrego comentarios en el código para explicarlo:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  var button = document.querySelector('button'),

    // Obtienes el valor de la propiedad en lugar de la 
    // propiedad del objeto, almacenándonse su valor
    // finalmente en la variable «text_button»:
    text_button = button.textContent;

  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Finalmente, cambias el valor de la variable
    // «text_button» y no el valor de la propiedad «textContent» del botón:
    text_button = "This text has been changed"
  });

})
```

```html
<button>This text dont change</button>
```

Efectivamente, no funciona.

La que sigue es lo deseado:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  var button = document.querySelector('button'),

    // Podrías definir una función:
    textButton = texto => {
      button.textContent = texto;
    };

  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Y llamarla:
    textButton("This text has been changed");
  });

})
```

```html
<button>This text dont change</button>
```

Esto, asumiendo que deseas evitar lo siguiente:

```js
button.textContent = "Algún texto";
```

Comment: gracias ! mi duda queda despejada 

Answer (score 2):

No funciona debido a que la asignación `text_button = button.textContent`, hace que la variable `text_button` almacene el `string` `"This text dont change"`. Sin embargo al reasignarle un valor en `text_button = "This text has been changed"`, solamente estas modificando el valor de una variable de tipo primitivo `string`, más no una propiedad del objeto `button`. Para modificar el nombre del botón tienes que acceder a la propiedad de dicho elemento, tal como ya habías comentado `button.textContent = "here goes something"`.